# Real world use cases of nosql database types

Tags: nosql, document, graph-databases, key-value-store, column-family

Could please someone helip me with a real world application of each nosql database types?

(graph, key-value stores, column-family, document)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite generic and will more than likely get closed by the moderators. A web search is your friend here. For example, here is a list of examples found by searching on "purpose built databases".

https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/